# Android WebView got white page nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to open webview on some android versions (4.4.4, 4.2.2) genymotion emulators, on both versions got white screen on the app and the following message on log cat:

```
W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView Rendering Issue in Android KitKat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675554/webview-rendering-issue-in-android-kitkat)

Comment: It dosen't worked for me, both threads. Also I have problem not only on 4.4.4

Comment: what was the solution?  Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

Try to set layer type like below. I think that problem is Kitkat issue.

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Edit: I make research about this issue, you can check these links below. Your question looks like a duplicate of them.

[Android Webview on 4.4 freezes with nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794478/android-webview-on-4-4-freezes-with-nativeondraw-failed-clearing-to-background)

[WebView Rendering Issue in Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675554/webview-rendering-issue-in-android-kitkat)

Comment: It dosen't worked for me, both threads and your solution, Also I have problem not only on 4.4.4

Comment: @LiorPozin did you find any solution? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.clevertap.com/androids-webview-is-broken/

Sizes that are implemented with percentages may crash your webview, I'm not really certain why, so if you can change that, your webview might work properly.

It took me half a day to find it, but it worked for me.